# How does initial state gets picked up in State Monad?

Tags: haskell

I was reading [LYAHFG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) and I can't get around understanding state monad.

In the book, state monad is defined as

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }  

instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState  
pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs) 

stackManip :: State Stack Int  
stackManip = do  
    push 3  
    a <- pop  
    pop  

runState stackManip [5,8,2,1]
```

The book explains this by using a stack, where stack is the state and an element is the result.

My question particularty is how does `runState stackManip [5,8,2,1]` work?

`runState` takes one argument, that's fine but `stackManip` doesn't take any argument. How does initial state `[5,8,2,1]` gets picked up?

Comment: In a nutshell, `runState m`, where `m` is a value in the State Monad, gives a function - to which you then pass the initial state and get out the result value and updated state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`runState` takes two arguments actually. When you declare a record

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

This defines the *function* `runState` with the following signature:

```
runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)
runState (State run) = run
```

You get the `s -> (a, s)` type alone when manipulating records explicitly (pattern-matching, construction, update):

```
pop = State { runState = \(x : s) -> (x, s) }
```

Comment: I believe that using `GADTSyntax` would be rather helpful to beginners, since it would avoid such misunderstandings, even if it's slightly more verbose.

Comment: @chi I just read about `GADTSyntax`. While it could be helpful, I think normal haskell is okay. Here, I struggled, since I was so lost into what a `state` monad is doing, I completely forgot records are nothing but pattern matching functions on the type. This was the first time I encountered a record as a function and the book never explicitly discussed it. While it should've been obvious, it also easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

A value of type `State` is just a (wrapped) function. The `Monad` instance for `State` "composes" those functions, rather than actually working directly with state. `runState` simply "unwraps" the function, giving you something you can directly apply to an initial state.

Another way of looking at it is that `runState` is an application operator, like `($)`. It applies a `State` (i.e., a state transformer) to an initial state.

Let's start with `evalState`, though, which just produces the result, not the new state.

```
head      $      [1,2,3] -- 1
pop  `evalState` [1,2,3] -- 1
```

`runState` just gives you a tuple consisting of the result *and* the new state.

```
pop `runState` [1,2,3] -- (1,[2,3])
```